# How to Mouse over the image in gallery

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a gallery with a mouse over function to make the image zoom towards another div. 
The gallery should change the image to an image div, but the function doesn't read the image URL as a background URL. Below is my code:

```
</head>
<body>

<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>


<div class="row">
<a href="#" onclick="setImage(this);"><img class="gallery" id="image1" src="img_nature.jpg" /></a>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="setImage(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="setImage(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="setImage(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="setImage(this);">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src=""width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>
<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>

<script>
// Initiate zoom effect:
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
function setImage(imgParent) {
    document.getElementById("myimage").src =       imgParent.childNodes[0].src;
var src =imgParent.childNodes[0].src:
}
</script>

</body>
```

Image of the script
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp

Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear but I can see an issue with your `setImage` function. The function is assigned inline on each `img` element other than `myImage` - so calling `childnodes[0]` makes no sense - you need the src of the image itself so you should be able to access it using `this` within the function like:

```
function setImage( img ) {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src=this.src;
}
```

or

using an event style

```
function setImage( e) {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src=e.target.src;
}
```

Presumably you are using the code found on W3Schools so maybe you can adapt this to suit - not tested though in any way.

```
function setImage( e ) {
    let img=document.getElementById( 'myimage' );
    let result=document.getElementById( 'myresult' );

    switch( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() ){
        case 'img': img.src=e.target.src; break;
        case 'a': img.src=e.target.querySelector('img').src; break;
    }
    // adapted from code found on w3schools
    /*
    result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    result.style.backgroundSize = ( img.width * cx ) + "px " + ( img.height * cy ) + "px";
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply i tried but images is not showing on the div. 

```<div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result" style="background-image: url(&quot;&quot;); background-size: 2250px 1800px; background-position: 0px -233.438px;"></div>```

Comment: the above will not work when assigned to the `a` tag ( ie: `<a href='' onclick='setImage(this);'>` )~ I did not notice that initially at all.